# Simple twitter program not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, twitter

I'm using this tutorial to practice creating an extremely basic twitter app: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/312325/Making-a-simple-Twitter-app-using-iOS-5-Xcode-4-2#setting-up-the-table-view

The only difference in my app is I'm only using tableView ViewController. I can't seem to get this to work.

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {


NSArray *tweets;
}
-(void)fetchTweets;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Twitter/Twitter.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self fetchTweets];
}

- (void)fetchTweets
{
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json"]];

    NSError* error;

    tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                             options:kNilOptions
                                               error:&error];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
});
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return tweets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
NSString *name = [[tweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"name"];

cell.textLabel.text = text;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"by %@", name];

return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
_tableView = nil;
[self setTableView:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
} else {
    return YES;
}
}

@end
```

Comment: any errors or log outputs? what is not working?

Comment: No errors, but no tweets are being retrieved in the simulator. I tried to NSLog tweet.count to check the data retrieval, but it does not output anything.

Comment: Your async / dispatch stuff looks a bit ugly. Have a look at NSURLConnection with the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to define delegate & datasource for your table, and didn't implement the protocols right as far as i see in your code,

try in your .h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    // your implementation...
}
```

and in your .m file in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

the `numberOfRows`, `cellForRow`, etc... methods wont work until you define your delegate & datasource for this table :)